# Need SQL select statement for the following

Tags: sql, database

1. Get the names of the employees who are working on the project named “Office Security  Project” and their responsibilities in the project
2. Give the qualification for the above query in:
    1) conjunctive normal form, and
    2) disjunctive normal form.

Comment: Can you give sample code or sample outputs? Database design?

Comment: How can one give SQL query without a table or column name. If you still want it here it is: select <columns> from <table> where <column> = 'office security project'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following relations
    EMP (eNo, eName, title)
    ASG (eNo, pNo, resp, dur)
    PROJ (pNo, pName, budget, loc)
Query: Get the names of the employees who are working on the project named “Office Security  Project” and their responsibilities in the project.

The query expressed in SQL is :

```
SELECT ENAME, RESP
FROM EMP, ASG, PROJ 
WHERE EMP.ENO = ASG.ENO  AND ASG.PNO = PROJ.PNO AND PNAME = “OFFICE SECURITY PROJECT’
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data you should use select

```
SELECT employee,responsibility FROM table_name WHERE project_name='Office_Security_Project';
```

Comment: but there are 3 tables emply ,resp and emp table so should we have to mention 3 tables in the select statement?